# El elemento aside tiene un desplazamiento extraño

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un layout sencillo, compuesto por un header, barra de navegación, un main, aside y footer.
Y me encuentro con un desplazamiento extraño en el elemento "aside", cada vez que le agrego texto al section que posicione al lado del mismo.
Estoy confundida, no se si debería cambiarle del display u agregarle position al aside y su elemento padre.
https://jsfiddle.net/7cu5sfbL/5/

Comment: Hola, usa `float: left;` envés de `display: inline-block;` en estas dos etiquetas `#main-content`  `aside`

Comment: Creo que es algo relacionado con la propiedad `line-height`. (poniéndola en `1em` se soluciona. Pero es mejor usar float, flex o grid)

Comment: Use float y me funciono perfecto. Gracias!